# Angular2 RC3 + new components not loading on route

Tags: angular, typescript

I need help in debugging this issue. I am almost at the end of my project. We build a website using angular2/seed project template by mgechev. We are using RC3 angular2 version. We are not going to update to ng2 for our first release. Now the problem started two days ago, where I had to write one more component and load it via route.

`likes.Routes.ts`

```
import { RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';

import { LikesComponent } from './index';

export const LikesRoutes: RouterConfig = [
  {
    path: 'likes',
    component: LikesComponent
  }
];
```

`likes.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

    @Component({
        moduleId: module.id,
        selector: 'sd-likes',
        templateUrl: 'likes.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['likes.component.css'],
        directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
    })
    export class LikesComponent {
        constructor() {
            console.log('Likes component is loaded...');
        }
    }
```

`app.routes.ts`

```
import {
    provideRouter,
    RouterConfig
} from '@angular/router';

import {
    HomeRoutes
} from './+home/index';
import {
    UserProfileRoutes
} from './+profile/index';
import {
    LoginRoutes
} from './+login/index';
import {
    SignupRoutes
} from './+signup/index';
import {
    ConfirmPasswordRoutes
} from './+confirmPassword/index';
import {
    ProfileSettingRoutes
} from './+profileSetting/index';
import {
    EntitiesRoutes
} from './+entities/index';
import {LikesRoutes} from './+likes/index';

const routes: RouterConfig = [
    ...HomeRoutes,
    ...UserProfileRoutes,
    ...LoginRoutes,
    ...SignupRoutes,
    ...ConfirmPasswordRoutes,
    ...ProfileSettingRoutes,
    ...EntitiesRoutes,
    ...LikesRoutes
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
    provideRouter(routes)
];
```

The route is configured properly in `app.routes.ts` file.
 Problem is I am not able to load `likes` component when I navigate to `/likes` url. Irony is, all my previously written component are loading properly with url. I do not see any error in my developer console nor in IDE console. I did some debugging on chrome developer window, I noticed my LikesComponent class is called (or loaded) but its constructor is not called. It irks me more when my previously written components are loaded correctly but not this one though they don't have much difference.

Please help me, what do I do to rectify this issue.

**EDIT: **
I have recently updated my vsCode to latest version (Aug month release). That was the only change in between.

Comment: why are you importing `LikeComponent` from `./index`  in your `like.Routes.ts`?

Comment: ok, even if I change it, result is same.

Comment: as there are no errors, my guess is your are missing loading `LikesComponent` in `app.routes.ts`

Comment: I edited my question and included `app.routes.ts` file. I have included `LikesRoutes' too. We do not include any component in `app.routes.ts` file. Let me know If I am right or wrong?